# Ошибка при установке через PIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

При попытке установки TensorFlow постоянно выдаёт следующую ошибку

C:\Users\Paul Anderson Jonson>pip install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Что делать?

Comment: Системные требования совпадают: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?

Answer (score 0):

Установить версию pip и Python которая бы удовлетворяла бы данную приблуду.

> TensorFlow 2 packages require a pip version >19.0.

Посмотрите какая у вас версия pip

Comment: версия pip 19.3.1

Comment: @PaulAndrsonJONSON  `Requires Python > 3.4 and pip >= 19.0`   и Python тоже удовлетворяет данной версии ?  Ибо я смотрю там же `Windows 7 or later (64-bit) (Python 3 only)`

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3

Comment: @PaulAndrsonJONSON там еще чуть ниже посмотрите список по версиям, возможно в них проблема 

`Windows
Python 3.5 CPU-only https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Python 3.5 GPU support https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Python 3.6 CPU-only https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
Python 3.6 GPU support https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: а не может быть ошибки на севере ?так как он пишет ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: @PaulAndrsonJONSON в документации и в ответах пишут в основном что конкретная версия tensorflow работает с определенной версией python.

Answer (score 0):

обновите python попробуйте установить с помощью .whl файла

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]